# Magento 2 custom module ui component admin form add fieldset within a field

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.2.2, ui-form, custom-field, fieldsets

Can one have a Fieldset within a field ?.
E.G:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">  
<fieldset name="custom_fieldset">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Fieldset</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">31</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="is_master_category">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 ....
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <fieldset name="custom_fieldset_in_field_2">
         <field name="custom_field_whithin_field_set_2">
         ...
         </field>
        </fieldset>
    </field>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**app/code/VendorNameSpace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="Test">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="parent">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="path">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="store_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="is_active">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable Category</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="include_in_menu">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Include in Menu</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="custom_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Fieldset</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">31</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="custom_js">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Js</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hope this achieve your requirement. thanks